Get report of all network events from the app under test in AWS Device Farm?
We are investigating switching from BrowserStack to AWS Device Farm for running our automated mobile UI tests with appium.  BrowserStack allows us to view all of the network activity of the running app, such as google analytics calls, etc.  Does AWS Device Farm support anything like that?  I see that I can view things in CloudTrail, but that appears to be just things I as the AWS user does, not the calls that the app under test makes as a simulated user.
